# Hibernate JOIN [some entity] ON unexpected token

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I use Hibernate **5.4.32.Final**, when I try to execute this query via spring data:

```
@Query("select new some.package.dto.TwoFieldDto(o.gln, u.email) "
            + "from OrganizationEntity o "
            + "join UserEntity u on u.organization.id = o.id "
            + "where o.gln in (:glnList)")
    List<TwoFieldDto<String, String>> findEmailListByGlnIn(List<String> glnList);
```

On starting application Hibernate throw SyntexException when it reaches to UserEntity token, and gives out unexpected token.

If I try to execute query from the UserEntity side, query compiles successfully. (Yes, I haven't get a link from OrganizationEntity to UserEntity)

Is this Hibernate version not supported JOIN ON syntex? (OrganizationEntity doesn't contain link on UserEntity, but UserEntity has it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@Query`annotation expects JPQL by default which has its own syntax. As far as I know, you can not do someting like `JOIN .. ON` in JPQL .
I do not know the association between your entities but it should look someting like this:

```
@Query("select new some.package.TwoFieldDto(o.gln, u.email) "
            + "from OrganizationEntity o "
            + "join o.UserEntity u "
            + "where o.gln in (:glnList)")
```

But for that to work, there has to be an association between `OrganizationEntity` and `UserEntity`.

As an alternative you can always use a native query, where you could do a `JOIN .. ON` in your native SQL dialect:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ....", nativeQuery = true)
```

But this should only be an option if you are sure that you can not do it with JPQL.

Answer (score 1):

In additional to the @Philipp answer: the best way to execute such a join from Hibernate is to add the bidirectional `@OneToMany` dependency to the `OrganizationEntity`, like this:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = UserEntity_.ORGANIZATION, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private List<UserEntity> organizationUsers;
```

And then you can easily write:

```
   @Query("select o.gln, u.email from OrganizationEntity o "
            + "join o.organizationUsers u "
            + "where o.pan in (:pans)")
    List<Object[]> findQuery(List<String> pans);
```